# How to make a custom NSView IBActions callable from menu items?

Tags: swift, macos, menuitem, nsview, responder-chain

I have a NSViewController that adds a custom NSView as a subview to the view controllers view. I would like to make the IBAction-methods of that custom view callable thru the First Responder object but the menu items that are wired to the corresponding IBActions of the custom view are always disabled.

I suspect that the reason is that the custom NSView is not added automatically to the responder chain. What should I do, as adding the exact same IBActions to my view controller just to call the same IBActions in the custom NSView is not very elegant?

Comment: Which object is first responder?

Comment: I don't know, but all IBActions defined in the active view controller are callable thru the responder chain, so I assume that my view does not have to be first responder to be able to respond to IBActions as long as it is are somewhere in the responder chain. My custom view returns acceptsFirstResponder true.